# PHP Arrayable Interface

Tags: php, arrays, interface, casting, magic-methods

I'm sure I read a while back about a new feature of PHP that was either a new magic method or a new interface so that you could implement Arrayable methods.

eg

```
interface Arrayable
{
    public function toArray();
}
```

Was I imagining it?

Comment: Not 5.4, and maybe not precisely what you mean, but was it this? http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Comment: If they were to add that feature (and I agree that it would be nice...), I'm sure they would add it as a magic method, like __toArray().  There does not appear to be one of those :(.

Comment: ArrayAccess is used to make an object behave like an array. toArray() would return a representation of the object as an array.

Comment: perhaps. I'm starting to think I may have been

Comment: Been down voted. Any feedback as to why?

Comment: added +1 to counter cowardly downvote.

Comment: Which kind of functionality would that interface add? You have missed to outline that in your question.

Comment: toArray would return an Array of the object like this http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.rowset.html#zend.db.table.rowset.to-array

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Was I imagining it?

Yes.

- There is no interface (PHP 5.4 or otherwise) within PHP for handling casting to an array.
- PHP 5.4.0 introduced the [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/jsonserializable) interface, perhaps you're thinking of that?
- There's also a draft RFC (one of several related) that suggests a `__toArray()` method; see [Request for Comments: Scalar Type Casting Magic Methods](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/object_cast_to_types)

Answer (score 29):

It's not in PHP itself, but Laravel has an interface that is intended for that exact purpose:

```
<?php namespace Illuminate\Contracts\Support;

interface Arrayable {

    /**
     * Get the instance as an array.
     *
     * @return array
     */
     public function toArray();

}
```

**Note:** In Laravel v4 the namespace was `Illuminate\Support\Contracts` and the interface name was `ArrayableInterface`.

Comment: I was kind of thinking of a native interface that you could then typecast objects to an array i.e. `$array = (array) $object;`

Comment: namespace Illuminate\Contracts\Support;

Comment: @gawpertron btw you can do that, it will result in array of property values keyed by property names - you can then access public properties, private&protected are prefixed in this conversion - more on that here in official docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting

Answer (score 2):

You are probably thinking of the [iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface. If you create a class that implements this you can iterate over it as if it is an array. For example, you can use it in a foreach() loop.

Also take a look at the other  [predefined interfaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.interfaces.php).

You can always write your own arrayable interface and then you can type hint for it or check it with [instanceof](http://www.php.net/instanceof) (see example #4) as you indicated you wanted to do in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841637/php-arrayable-interface#comment15747192_11841696).

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php has the same idea as the Arrayable interface. It's not about making an object traversable, but being able to return a representation of the object as an Array.

Comment: Or type casting to an array ie `$foo = (array) $arrayableObject`

Comment: Then just write a toArray() method. You are best placed to know how your object should be represented as an array. I don't think PHP could be expected to guess that for you.

Comment: I plan to, but to check if the object is an `interfaceof` of a standard interface would be tidy.

Answer (score 2):

There's this (which is fairly useless IMO)
http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php

and also this (which does come in handy but always requires a type check before using it)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php

But no way to handle object to array conversion implicitly.